# event listener not picking up Laravel Livewire emit from mount() method (but working when firing from blade)

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have [nested Livewire components](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/nesting-components), where the "child" [fires an event](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events) to the "parent".
The issue is that it does not reach the listener when firing from the child's (mount) method.
Maybe the listener is not yet available when firing the event from child?
It does work when firing from the child's blade, using `wire:click="$emit(...)"` or global JavaScript.

Analogy for my setup: the `first` method gets the Posts and the `second` method gets+manages the Comments, and I want to let `first` know how many comments are on the page so it can update the counter. This can be done as part of the mount() where I get the Comments.

How do I fire an event from the child's `mount()` method, and/or are other ways more suitable?

**First.php**

```
protected $listeners = ['testEmit'];

public function testEmit() {
   Log::info("testEmit listener"); // only received when firing from blade
}
```

**first.blade.php**

```
@livewire('second')
```

**Second.php**

```
    public function buttonClick()
    {
        // works
        $this->emit('testEmit', 'Second (method buttonClick)');
    }

    public function mount()
    {
        // not working (is sent but not received)
        $this->emit('testEmit', 'Second (method mount)');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        // does not work (does work after buttonClick emit)
        $this->emit('testEmit', 'Second (method render)');

        return view('livewire.second')->layout('layouts.guest');
    }
```

**second.blade.php**

```
<div>
    <button wire:click="$emit('testEmit')"> <!-- this works fine -->
</div>
<div>
   <button wire:click="buttonClick">test (calls method)</button>
</div>
<script>
//  Livewire.emit('testEmit') // this works fine
</script>
```

**update**: added more details/examples to Second.php and second.blade.php

Comment: Try emitting under `render()` menthod.

Comment: that did not work. It would call the emit in render only after calling a method. I will update the example the above to show the details.

Comment: Did you ever get this working @wivku? I'm in the same situation

Comment: No, situation is unchanged.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone stumbling on this in the future, I found this to work:

//in *.blade file

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        Livewire.emit("emit_to_parent");
    });
</script>
```

//in livewire component

```
protected $listeners = ["emit_to_parent"];

public function emit_to_parent()
{
    $this->emit("foo");
}
```

For background, this issue explains why it doesn't work

[Cannot emit events from mount method #598](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/598)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use the `wire:init` directive as suggested [here](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/598#issuecomment-984491103)

```html
<div wire:init="$emit('testEmit')">
    ...
</div>
```

See https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/defer-loading#introduction

Answer (score -1):

In such case, I would suggest to keep emit code in one function only.

```
public function mount()
{
    $this->buttonClick();
}

public function render()
{
    $this->buttonClick();
    return view('livewire.second')->layout('layouts.guest');
}

public function buttonClick()
{
    $this->emit('testEmit', 'Second (method buttonClick)');
}
```

Comment: the point is that when called from mount() or render() -directly or via a function- the emit() is not working. So, $this->buttonClick() in mount() or render() has no effect.